# Can Romanians be placed in Finland in Stalingrad?

Tags: avalon-hill

In Avalon Hill’s classic game Stalingrad, may Romainan units be placed in Finland at the start of the game as part of the 8 Combat factors that can be placed in Finland by the Germans?

Answer (score 1):

After looking around through other AH Stalingrad rules (later editions and addenda), I found that Romanians can indeed be placed in Finland at game’s beginning.
Rules state that a maximum of 8 German and or Romanian Combat factors can be placed in Finland as part of the 8 axis points that may be allocated there.  So you could have 4 German and 4 Romanian Combat factors or 2 German and 6 Romanian and so on.